# Obtaining md5 during wget

Tags: wget, checksum

I'm `wget`'ing huge files (over 100GB) and then comparing my md5sum to the sum posted in the repository.  Believe it or not, `md5sum` takes a nontrivial amount of time to run on a file of this size, so I'd like to get the sum in parallel with the download.

What's the best way to do this?  I don't see a `wget` option to calculate MD5 during download (surprisingly) so I guess using `tee` would be the way to go?!

Comment: Is this possible? I'm pretty sure you need the entire binary to check the hash. I doubt even breaking it into steps (ie hash as it is downloaded) would be possible seeing as you might not be receiving the file in sequential order. Either way, I would be happy to see if someone has a solution.

Comment: @MaxMackie: It is definitely possible: since I'm downloading the entire file, wget could theoretically run it through MD5.  Unf, it doesn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, this might be possible:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/file | tee file | md5sum > file.md5
```

However, this assumes you have the hash in a file beforehand.

Comment: This looks fine, and I don't see how it assumes anything about having the "has in a file beforehand". It just generates the sum as you go along and writes it to a file that you can use to compare later. The only catch might be the memory overhead.

Comment: @Caleb What memory overhead? `md5sum` (and any other common hash algorithm such as the SHA family) operates in constant memory. They're designed to work on streams.

Comment: with an additional `awk` at the end you can remove the ` -` a the end automatically. `wget -O - "https://example.org/myFile.jpg" | tee file | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' > md5.txt`